# Spring Data Mongo: How to save batch ignoring all duplicate key errors?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following domain object:

```
@Document
class Foo {
    @Id
    private final String bar;
    private final String baz;
    // getters, setters, constructor omitted
}
```

Which is inserted as follows:

```
Collection<Foo> foos = ...;
mongoTemplate.insert(foos, Foo.class);
```

How to save all results in one call ignoring all duplicate key exceptions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched through spring data mongo documentation and other resources, but didn't find expected answer.

Seems like Mongo inserts batch docs until unique key constraint is met, and it's up to DB to decide.

So for example if you need to insert 100 docs and document on position 50 already exists in DB then the first 49 will be inserted and the second 50 will not.

What I came up is the next solution:

```
Set<String> ids = foos.stream().map(Foo::getBar).collect(toSet()); // collect all ids from docs that will be inserted
WriteResult writeResult = mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").in(ids)), Foo.class); // perform remove with collected ids
mongoTemplate.insert(foos, Foo.class); // now can safely insert batch
```

So DB will be called twice.
Also as `bar` is indexed field the remove operation will be fast.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was not suitable to allow modification/overwriting of the existing documents as in @marknorkin's answer. Instead, I only wanted to insert *new* documents. I came up with this using `MongoOperations`, which is injectable in Spring. The code below is in Kotlin.

```
 try {
        // we do not want to overwrite existing documents, especially not behind the event horizon
        // we hence use unordered inserts and supresss the duplicate key exceptions
        // as described in: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#unordered-inserts
        mongoOps.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, EventContainer::class.java)
            .insert(filtered)
            .execute()
      } catch (ex: BulkOperationException) {
        if (!isDuplicateKeyException(ex)) {
          throw ex
        }
      }
```

With this little helper

```
private fun isDuplicateKeyException(ex: BulkOperationException): Boolean {
    val duplicateKeyErrorCode = 11000
    return ex.errors.all { it.code == duplicateKeyErrorCode }
}
```

Comment: These answers are ridiculous. Spring data mongo code is doing this intentionally https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/b01b25ef9325cb8c64db7ead65d37c0057af1404/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoExceptionTranslator.java#L104 I have no idea why